# My keyboard repeats the keys even though I haven't released it

Tags: usb, drivers, keyboard, port, case

My keyboard repeats the key even if I don't release it.

When I press a key, my keyboard "drops" it and repeats it again, making it difficult to type or play video games.

I tested my keyboard at a testing site for such hardware. When I press a key on the site, its counterpart lights up. The problem is that mine is flashing. Indicating that, they are released and pressed again.

I tested the keyboard on another PC and it works fine. The drivers work fine, they are the same on both PCs. I tried different USB ports(USB 2 and 3) and the problem persists.

If I put a hand on the case and a few fingers on the outer metal cover that protects the ports, the problem seems to disappear.

Update: When I place my hand on the metal grille and on the turret, I sometimes notice a small current.

Case:  Montech X3 Glass,
Motherboard: PRIME B550-PLUS

If you could help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Before further investigation, do you have another keyboard to try out? Also, make sure you do not use a USB3 port. There are two USB2.0 ports on your motherboard as indicated here (the two black ports) https://imgur.com/Uyj0x1j - Get another keyboard then report back.

Comment: Good afternoon,  @JohnnyVegas . I tried it with another keyboard, I thought the keyboard was broken so I bought a new one and realized the problem was with the PC.

I connected it to the USB 2.0 ports on the motherboard and the ones that come on the PC tower, but the problem persists.

I think it's an electrical problem as another user mentioned, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Are you plugging in your PC PSU directly to wall outlet or are you using any extension boards or those devices than convert 1 single socket to multiple, kind of stuff and plugging your PSU into such devices? Can you test connecting your PC to a different wall outlet may be in another room?

Comment: "Can you try plugging your PC into a different wall outlet that may be in another room?"

I have a whole house uninterruptible power supply, I connect my PC directly to the UPS and now I plug the PC into an wall outlet and it works perfectly. Although I still feel the electric current a little, it's okay.

Thank you very much @patkim, I was lost. The problem is solved.

How to mark your answer?

Comment: Hi @Maxbr24 - Glad to know that issue is solved. I feel there's no good enough info on underlying cause to write a good answer from my side.  May be the UPS or Earthing or any other variable  is the culprit, you may need to investigate further. For now you may answer your own question and mark (Accept) it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the plugin on another outlet, and it works, it only works on that outlet. I assume it is an electrical problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that touching the computer causes the problem to disappear
may indicate that you have static electricity accumulation in the computer.

I suggest to verify your electrical connections and your computer.
You should also try earthing the computer with a metallic wire to
some conducting pipe or similar.